# Aframe Dynamic Canvas as Texture

Tags: javascript, canvas, aframe

I was trying to use a canvas as texture in my aframe project. I found some instructions [here](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/material.html#canvas-textures). It mentioned:

> The texture will automatically refresh itself as the canvas changes.

However, I gave it a try today and the canvas could only be changed / updated in init function. Afterwards the update to canvas cannot be reflected. Here is my implementation:

```
module.exports = {
  'canvas_component': {
    schema: {
      canvasId: { type: 'string' }
   },

   init: function () {
     this.canvas = document.getElementById(this.data.canvasId);
     this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

     this.ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
     this.ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);

     setTimeout(() => {
       this.ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFF00";
       this.ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
     }, 2000);
   }
 }
```

The color change of of the texture was never changed. Is there anything I missed? Thank you so much for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could never get it to work with those instructions (never checked out if bug or improper use though), but you can achieve the same with Three.js:

```
// assuming this is inside an aframe component
init: function() {
  // we'll update this manually
  this.texture = null
  let canvas = document.getElementById("source-canvas");
  // wait until the element is ready
  this.el.addEventListener('loaded', e => {
     // create the texture
     this.texture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(canvas);

     // get the references neccesary to swap the texture
     let mesh = this.el.getObject3D('mesh')
     mesh.material.map = this.texture
     // if there was a map before, you should dispose it
  })
},
tick: function() {
  // if the texture is created - update it
  if (this.texture) this.texture.needsUpdate = true
}
```

Check it out in [this](https://aframe-draw-texture.glitch.me/) glitch.

Instead using the `tick` function, you could update the texture whenever you get any callback from changing the canvas (mouse events, source change).

Answer (score 1):

The docs are out of date, I've made a pull request to update them. Here is the code that shows how to do it now:

src: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/4878

which points to: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/b164623dfa0d2548158f4b7da06157497cd4ea29/examples/test/canvas-texture/components/canvas-updater.js

We can quickly turn that into a component like this, for example:

```js
/* global AFRAME */

AFRAME.registerComponent('live-canvas', {
  dependencies: ['geometry', 'material'],

  schema: {
    src: { type: "string", default: "#id"}
  },

  init() {
    if (!document.querySelector(this.data.src)) {
      console.error("no such canvas")
      return
    }
    this.el.setAttribute('material',{src:this.data.src})
  },

  tick() {
    var el = this.el;
    var material;

    material = el.getObject3D('mesh').material;
    if (!material.map) { 
      console.error("no material map")
      this.el.removeAttribute('live-canvas')
      return; 
    }
    material.map.needsUpdate = true;
  }
});
```

(remember to declate your components before your scene...)

usage:

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="example-canvas"></canvas>
  <a-scene>
    <a-box live-canvas="src:#example-canvas;"></a-box>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```

live glitch code demo here:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/live-canvas-demo?path=index.html%3A58%3A43

You can of course be more efficient than a tick handler if you just intentionally run the equivalent code manually whenever you update the canvas yourself, if that makes more sense / isn't happening frame-by-frame.